Git Bash doesn't have any formatting
So my git bash look like this and idk how to fix it. It makes me feel hard to see the line while there is no space between them.
my git bash
i tried to reinstall it a few times but it didn't work.
However this problem does not happen to other users on my windows.
it should look like this
I tried to search it on google but nothing actually helps. Then I reinstalled it but still nothing.

The missing colors and git magic in the prompt are due to some bash initialization files not being read. Maybe for some reason the .bashrc is in the wrong directory. There is sometimes a strange interaction between the Windows HOME environment variable and what the msys underlying Windows git thinks your home is. Try cygpath -w ~ and see where bash thinks your init files should be.

Another thing is that the canonical way to start git bash is probably by double-clicking some cmd file in the install directory.
